# How do I find the version number in 'ribbon' versions of Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

How do I find the version number in 'ribbon' versions of Microsoft Office?

The *Help* menu is gone, and menu *Help/About* had the version information in earlier versions of Microsoft Office.

Comment: (I needed this information, could not find it on Super User and documented it here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Office 2010, the version information is now in the menu item *Help* in the *File* menu (for instance, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and choose *Help*):

[image]

---

In Office 2007, click the *Office* button, choose *<App> Options* at the bottom of the menu, then open the *Resources* section.

[image: Office menu] [image: Options window]

Comment: re Circles: yes, the Meta folks do call it that. It is an official meme - *[Freehand Circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)*.

Comment: It's still just ALT+F, go to HELP.